# How do I validate and test the tandem creation of associated objects in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec, associations

In my app, when a User is initialized, I want them to build 5 items. I've seen tests that assert there are, for example, `expect(@user.items.count).to eq(5)`. However, I've been trying to validate the length of items and test the validation itself, not the number of objects associated with a user. Is this even possible? If so, what's the best way of going about this?

Here is the relevant code I have so far.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ITEMS_ALLOWED = 5
  has_many :items

  validates :items, length: {is: ITEMS_ALLOWED}
  after_initialize :init_items

  def init_items
    ITEMS_ALLOWED.times { items.build }
  end
...
```

My relevant test, using RSpec, Faker and FactoryGirl

```
describe User do
  before :each do
    @user = build(:user, username: "bob")
    @user.save
  end

  it "is invalid with more than 5 items" do
    user3 = build(:user)
    user3.save
    expect(user3.items.create(name: "test")).not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

Currently the test tries to validate the item that's created. I tried to move the validation to the Item class instead, but I'm receiving the error, undefined method items for nil on the line that tries to call `user.items.count`.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :number_of_items, length: {is: 5}

  def number_of_items
    errors.add("User must have exactly 5 items.") unless user.items.count == 5
  end
end
```

================
Update: Failure Message when there are no validations in the Item class.

```
Failures:

  1) User initialization is invalid with more than 5 items
     Failure/Error: expect(user3.items.create(name: "test")).not_to be_valid
       expected #<Item id: 16, name: "test", user_id: 3, photo: nil, created_at: "2014-01-14 00:24:11", updated_at: "2014-01-14 00:24:11", photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil, photo_updated_at: nil, description: nil> not to be valid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your `User` instance, the `init_items` is being called and the `Item` instances are being created. However, the user's id is not defined at that point, so the `user_id` value of the created items is `nil`. This in turn results in the table's `user` method returning `nil` in your `number_of_items` validation.

When you remove the `Item` validations, then you're RSpec example will fail because you're doing a validation on an `Item` (i.e. the result of `user3.items.create`) rather than validating the resulting `User`. Instead, you can do something like this:

```
user3.items.create(name: "test")
expect(user3).to_not be_valid
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! How would you implement the validation? I'm having a hard time figuring out where to insert it. The process I see is: build user --> build items --> save user --> save items

Comment: Actually, after looking at this some more, I think you should be able to do it without bypassing validation, but the validation needs to definitely be on User. If you remove the Item validation, do you still have a problem? If so, can you post the specifics?

Comment: Added failure message into original post

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using `after_initialize`. It is called whenever an object is instantiated, even after merely calling `User.find`. If you must use it, add a test for `new_record?` so that the items are only added for new `User`'s.

An alternative approach is to write a builder method to use instead of User.new.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Baae
  ITEMS_ALLOWED = 5
  has_many :items

  validates :items, length { is: ITEMS_ALLOWED }

  def self.build_with_items
    new.tap do |user|
      user.init_items
    end
  end

  def init_items
    ITEMS_ALLOWED.times { items.build }
  end
end

describe User do
  context "when built without items" do
    let(:user) { User.new }

    it "is invalid" do
      expect(user.items.size).to eq 0
      expect(user.valid?).to be_false
    end
  end

  context "when built with items" do
    let(:user) { User.build_with_items }

    it "is valid" do
      expect(user.items.size).to eq 5
      expect(user.valid?).to be_true
    end
  end
end
```

This allows you to separate the item initialization from the user initialization, in case you end up wanting to have a `User` without items. In my experience, this works out better than requiring all newed up objects to be built the same way. The tradeoff is that you now need to use `User.build_with_items` in the `new` action in the controller.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought to use the tap method. I think the problem Peter pointed out persists though; items.build try to tie the item to a user_id foreign key and the user hasn't been saved yet (hence no validation yet either).

Comment: You may have been tripped up by using `count` vs `size`. `count` does a DB query, `size` and `length` do not.